# Почему в указанном предложении нет ни двоеточия, ни точки с запятой?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, двоеточие, бессоюзное, точка-с-запятой

Дмитрий Емец, Великое Нечто (2006)

*Под дубом прогуливалась раскормленная болонка, которая от толщины уже разучилась тявкать, а только чихала. Орлан хищным круглым глазом уставился на собачку, всем своим огромным телом испытывая голод. Этой жирной моськи ему хватило бы надолго, а что, если снова пренебречь запретом? В конце концов, если рассуждать логически, вряд ли это изменит баланс на планете. **На вид болонка такая аппетитная(,) жирная спина, тонкие ножки(,) должно быть, на вкус она восхитительна…***

Казалось бы, на месте указанных запятых надо поставить двоеточие и точку с запятой, но автор этого не делает.
Почему? Здесь же раскрытие темы, отдалённость тематики для двух сообщений.

Нарушение правил или нет? Нужно ли редактировать текст в таких случаях?

Comment: Отдаленность тематики? А там разве нет вывода?

Comment: Есть предположение - должно быть. Я же имею в виду, что запятой здесь вроде бы недостаточно, надо бы использовать более сильный знак, но автор так не считает. Как бы вы оформили предложение? Стали бы редактировать рукопись?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если бы я была огромным голодным орланом и видела [раскормленную собачку](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%85%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%85%D1%83%D0%B0&sa=X&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAONQF1LRr0jWv7Dxwr4Lu4F474VdFzZYXWwCcS82AukNF_sdikqV5ECq9HP1DbIzMoox5bXkclNLEq30KwoS81JzgGrz85JTC0qsijNTUssTK4ujZFG1KKBauIhRAGR-UWpaZl5qbmpeib7BL0bZC_MvzLuwFIinXZhxYarChekXJgCFFgAFFl5YvYCFZQEL0wIWhgUsjItY5S8sQjH-YvuFHRdbLzYDOWDyFpskg9bUKq69B_SdT1vt0Qw_Nv_4_e6pTz_eY90OAOqZTD8EAQAA&biw=1366&bih=657&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=09G05dsyTLLxtM%252CgnU-pTjASMjN2M%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kQW-B4phvPjA_UnF1B8ONAg5hAWmA&ved=2ahUKEwjZltKwvb3yAhUsi8MKHT1uC0EQ9QF6BAgPEAE#imgrc=KjgS8h403zf4yM), то представлялась бы она мне толстой сарделькой на небольшой вилочке.

Изображение болонки годится и для первой части предложения, и для последней:
на вид болонка такая аппетитная — жирная спина, тонкие ножки;
жирная спина, тонкие ножки — должно быть, на вкус она восхитительна.

Пунктуация тогда могла быть такой:
*На вид болонка такая аппетитная — **жирная спина, тонкие ножки,** — должно быть, на вкус она восхитительна…*
В этом случае описание пухлой животинки становится вставкой и, соответственно, относится только к первой части. Возможно, именно этого автор и хотел избежать, поставив только запятые (тем более что [правила](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=125#pp125) разрешают).

Comment: Из-за того, что в предложении имеются и другие запятые, для вставки необходимы тире (чтоб вообще её **разглядеть**). Пункт 3: ***В редких случаях** вставная конструкция выделяется запятыми.* Эти редкие случаи смахивают на авторскую пунктуацию.

Comment: Про сардельку на вилке   очень сильно сказано))

Answer (score 1):

Розенталь:
Иногда дополнительный знак подчеркивает пояснительные или причинно-следственные отношения между частями предложения, например:
*Дети прекратили игры, — очевидно, звонок на урок прозвучал.

Бабушка уже топчется около стола, — **должно быть**, хочет зажечь огонь* (Гладков).

Сделал бы так:
*На вид болонка такая аппетитная: жирная спина, тонкие ножки, — должно быть, на вкус она восхитительна…*

Ошибка — когда нельзя ставить. А крайне нежелательно (как здесь) — близится к ошибке.

Автор всё смешал в одном казане — везде запятые, но ведь ситуации разные. Возможно, логика такая:
*На вид болонка такая аппетитная (1 факт), [у неё] жирная спина, тонкие ножки [2 факт], должно быть, на вкус она восхитительна (3 факт)…* || Нет взаимоотношений между частями. Как-то тупо.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Вам не нравится, стали бы править автора? О вашем варианте.  Два очень сильных знака (двоеточие и запятая/тире) в небольшом предложении?  Есть ли для этого основания?

Comment: Стал бы: ситуации разные — знаки разные. При выводе ставится тире с запятой. У Розенталя много примеров.

Comment: Так...  бедные авторы, достанется им от вас.  Я не согласна. Мне Емец очень нравится – причем в первую очередь не сюжеты,  а язык его книг. Лаконичный, выразительный, точно подобранный. А вы его править собрались!

Comment: Ну тогда не буду. Тогда пусть будут три факта.

Comment: Тогда? Интересно, что вы имеете в виду.  Не хотите со мной спорить или я вас убедила? А отсутствие сильных знаков можете обосновать?

Comment: Чтобы было так, как вы хотите. А вы пока ничем не убеждали — так давайте.

Comment: У меня есть версия, но мне хочется, чтобы другие ответили. Подожду еще.

Answer (score 1):

Комментарий к ответу

Римма, большое спасибо за  ответ с иллюстрациями – собачки  и правда восхитительны… Также меня порадовало **ваше понимание предложения** – вероятно,  и орлан  в своих мыслях **отдельно выделял** те конкретные детали, о которых вы говорите.

Мы же в  нашем же случае обозначим **последовательность мыслей** – то, что называется **«потоком сознания»**. Это представляется более важным – как мне кажется, читатель должен оценить такой подход. Тем более что весь абзац оформлен преимущественно запятыми.

**Правила** в данном случае не запрещают такое оформление:  Если предикативные части бессоюзного сложного предложения близки между собой по смыслу, то между ними ставятся запятые. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=149#pp149

**В грамматике** в этом случае говорится о соединительно-распространительном отношении между простыми предложениями, что соответствует **распространительной запятой**.

Также нужно помнить и **о графическом оформлении** текста – не стоит перегружать небольшое предложение обилием знаков.

Answer (score 0):

Двоеточие ставится, если 2 часть СПП содержит пояснение, дополнение. Можно предположить пояснение. Но если жирная спинка - это аппетитно, то тонкие ножки уж никакого аппетита у орлана вызвать не могут. Поэтому, наверное, и нет двоеточия. Чего-то автор текста не учел.